# NestJS Kafka e2e test examples

Tags: nestjs, kafkajs, nestjs-testing

Does anybody know how to write e2e tests for Kafka to test producing/consuming events ?.

I have had a look at the NestJS github repo below and cant find anything.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample

Comment: You can find e2e examples for NestJS MicroServices - https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/integration/microservices/e2e

Comment: The latest git commit messages on the kafka tests look like it was to skip them. Do you have any examples of working kafka e2e tests ?, it would be useful to see how to test consuming kafka events ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an open issue for more documentation on how to test NestJS microservices

https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1954